# how to fix leetcode98 Validate Binary Search Tree with recursive function?

Tags: scala, recursion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoFiP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz55w.png)

The point of this  problem is the two  variation .'last' and 'isFirst' not be init right before LeetCode next use this function . they save the last  value   and not be init again .
I cannot AC this question use this thought .
help me !
English is bad ,sorry !

```scala
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode(var _value: Int) {
 *   var value: Int = _value
 *   var left: TreeNode = null
 *   var right: TreeNode = null
 * }
 */
object Solution {
   var last: Double = -Double.MaxValue
  var isFirst = true

  def isValidBST(root: TreeNode): Boolean = {

    if (root == null) {

      return true
    }
    if (isValidBST(root.left)) {
      if (last < root.value || isFirst) {
        isFirst = false
        last = root.value
        return isValidBST(root.right)
      }
    }
    last = -Double.MaxValue
    isFirst = true
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: Try solving this without using any assignment operator.

Comment: `root.value` is an `Int`, so you need to go _just beyond_ `Int.MinValue` and `Int.MaxValue`. (Hint: You don't need `Double`.) Also, this is Scala. Don't use `return`. Can be done in ~7 lines of code.

Comment: thanks ,this problem is finish . by the way ,scale recursive function need  return keyword .

Comment: @Anthony; No it does not. Recursion is common in Scala but `return` is not. Experienced Scala programmers never use it.